# CPM failed to get the hash for HEAD

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake for the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0 FATAL_ERROR)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CPM configuration
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
set(CPM_MODULE_NAME "arc_ball")
set(CPM_LIB_TARGET_NAME ${CPM_MODULE_NAME})

if ((DEFINED CPM_DIR) AND (DEFINED CPM_UNIQUE_ID) AND (DEFINED CPM_TARGET_NAME))
  set(CPM_LIB_TARGET_NAME ${CPM_TARGET_NAME})
  set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CPM_DIR})
  include(CPM)
else()
  set (CPM_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cpm-packages" CACHE TYPE STRING)
  find_package(Git)
  if(NOT GIT_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CPM requires Git.")
  endif()
  if (NOT EXISTS ${CPM_DIR}/CPM.cmake)
    message(STATUS "Cloning repo (https://github.com/iauns/cpm)")
    execute_process(
      COMMAND "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" clone git@github.com:iauns/cpm.git ${CPM_DIR}
      RESULT_VARIABLE error_code
      OUTPUT_QUIET ERROR_QUIET)
    if(error_code)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "CPM failed to get the hash for HEAD")
    endif()
  endif()
  include(${CPM_DIR}/CPM.cmake)
endif()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CPM Modules
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# ++ MODULE: GLM
CPM_AddModule("GLM"
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/iauns/cpm-glm"
  GIT_TAG "1.0.2"
  USE_EXISTING_VER TRUE
  EXPORT_MODULE TRUE    # Use EXPORT_MODULE sparingly. We expose GLM's interface
  )                     # through our own interface hence why we export it.

# This call will ensure all include directories and definitions are present
# in the target. These correspond to the modules that we added above.
CPM_InitModule(${CPM_MODULE_NAME})

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Source
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Globbing has some downsides, but the advantages outweigh the
# disadvantages.
file (GLOB Sources
  "arc-ball/*.cpp"
  "arc-ball/*.hpp"
  )

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Library setup
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Build the library.
add_library(${CPM_LIB_TARGET_NAME} ${Sources})
if (NOT EMSCRIPTEN AND CPM_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(${CPM_LIB_TARGET_NAME} ${CPM_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

My system is windows 8.1 and I'm using Visual Studio 11 2012 as a generator. However when I try to configure, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at 
CMakeLists.txt:26 (message):
  CPM failed to get the hash for HEAD
```

Meaning that it's happening on that line:`COMMAND "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" clone git@github.com:iauns/cpm.git ${CPM_DIR}`

Would anyone know why?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Remove(temporary) `OUTPUT_QUIET` and `ERROR_QUIET` and see what `git` outputs with that command. Also you can try to execute given command by hands(values of `GIT_EXECUTABLE` and `CPM_DIR` variables you can print with `message` command before `execute_process()`.

Comment: Removing OUTPUT_QUIET doesn't change a thing. However thanks to you I have notice that GIT_EXECUTABLE's value is: "C:/cygwin64/bin/git.exe" and maybe it should be "C\Program File\Git\bin\git.exe" don't you think?

Comment: Tried to change it and apparently it doesn't work. I get the exact same error.

Comment: What output(error log) of the git command is? It may help in futher investigations. (Thats why `*_QUIET` variables was removed: they force `execute_process()` call to ignore output of the command).